# Linking a route to a class in Flask

Tags: python, flask

[image]

I'm looking at an open source app https://github.com/AlvinCJin/deepfit-app/tree/master/app

This is using flask-admin for admin purposes/ On the page https://github.com/AlvinCJin/deepfit-app/blob/master/app/main/views.py:

```
# admin management setup
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Post, db.session))
path = op.join(os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/../../"), 'static')  # need to get parent path of this code
admin.add_view(FileAdmin(path, '/static/', name='Static Files'))
```

This works fine as far as producing a helpful dashboard but is unsecured.

I have flask-login installed and I read the section http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#rolling-your-own , but it is unclear to me how to link the class discussed:

```
class MicroBlogModelView(sqla.ModelView):

def is_accessible(self):
    return login.current_user.is_authenticated

def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
    # redirect to login page if user doesn't have access
    return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
```

with the admin route. I'm used to the idea of linking routes to module functions in flask , but not classes.

How can this be done?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/

Comment: Classes don't return Response objects. That's why routes are always on functions. Blueprints are often used to organize routes. Nothing is stopping you from using classes to separate out route functions.

Comment: Thank you that helps me, but how would you combine routes and a class the way they discuss it above. Would you mind providing an example.

Comment: The code above uses Flask Admin, which I've not used